# GRUB hangs on emergency boot

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, grub

I am trying to get a server going and was extremely excited when I found out it would automatically boot if the power just suddenly stopped. So if i were to unplug the server while it was still running it would boot next time I plugged it in. This will be very useful for if my server location has a power outage because it takes the generators ~3min to kick in. When this happens I have to start the Linux server 14.04 manually from GRUB, it wont auto-start. Is there any fix for this or possibly a way to disable this and enable remote power up. I am currently using a Dell PowerEdge 840.

Comment: Exactly what is GRUB doing? What is your GRUB configuration?

Comment: It is supposed to go straight into the default os (Ubuntu server)

Comment: It does but do it if I do a normal reboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GRUB, you can define a default menu item and a timeout. Both **must** to be defined in order to achieve auto-boot after power outage.

GRUB 0.97 (http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/grub.html)

GRUB config file: '/boot/grub/menu.lst', you must edit this file with any text editor like 'nano'.
The variables are 'default' and 'timeout'.

GRUB 2.x ([http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html])

GRUB config file: /boot/grub/grub.cfg

The variables are 'default' and 'timeout'. If your system uses a 'simple configuration' of GRUB, you need to set GRUB_DEFAULT and GRUB_TIMEOUT in '/etc/default/grub' file and run 'grub-mkconfig' utility.  See also: section "Simple configuration" in GRUB 2.x manual.

Based on your version of Ubuntu, your GRUB version is probably 2.

BTW, because your generators takes about 3 minutes to start, I think an UPS would be a good investing. Power outages isn't good for file systems of any modern OS.